# How to make a for loop slower?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setInterval(()=>{
    for (j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
    }
})
```

I have this loop setup, is there any way to make the for loop go slower? obj length can be as big as 200-400 arrays. Jquery answers accepted.

Comment: You do want to loop your loop like that with `setInterval`, right?

Comment: What is the real problem you're having? Why would you want the loop to be slower?

Comment: Yeah, I want setInterval on it. The problem is that I get very high cpu usage everytime the loop runs because it runs trought so many arrays at once every 2 sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise based delay:

```js
const delay = x => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, x));
(async () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        console.log(j);

        await delay(1000);
    }
})();
```

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Comment: @Ilyaskarim: No he/she's not.

Comment: "Jquery answers accepted." at the last of question text.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim: That does not mean **only** Jquery answers accepted. Which would be utterly stupid.

Comment: You can use delay function to delay the execution of code provided by jquery.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim: Or, you could just not.

Comment: Can you just explain the promise part fast? If it's not too much work tho

Comment: @Xardas105: `delay` creates a `Promise` that resolves (`res`) when the timeout ends. This then can be used in `async` functions with `await` to wait the given number of milliseconds.

Comment: @Xardas105: Here would be links to introductions on [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) and [async functions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions).